# ERROR al restaurar una base de datos SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

estoy intentando restaurar una base de datos, ya lo e realizado varias veces
pero resulta que ahora no alguien podría ayudarme en esto

Comment: Bienvenido Briann, te aconsejo que te des una vuelta por el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) en concreto por los apartados [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Así podrás entender la filosofía de este sitio antes de empezar a insultar a gente que no conoces de nada. Sería raro que te baneen, pero no tanto que se elimine o bloquee la pregunta si esta no está dentro de las características del sitio.

Comment: No soy un experto en SQL pero, por lo que puedo leer en tu imagen, estas cargando una base de datos sobre otra ya existente, y te esta diciendo que no puedes hacer tal cosa. ¿Por que no pones en tu pregunta, editándola, que pasos has seguido, tamaño de la BD, programa/sistema operativo donde pruebas. Cosas que, parece que no, pero pueden marcar una diferencia a la hora de trabajar y a la hora de que podamos responderte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

le aconsejo revisar que no este intentando restaurar la base de datos sobre una ya existente. ya que esta generaria conflicto, este link podria ayudarle.  [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978964)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar el nombre de los archivos, que dispones en la página Files por algunos que no existan seguro. Es posible que tu conflicto venga dado porque la bbdd que esta formada por varios archivos entra en colisión con archivos existentes.